# Setting Scrape Intervalls for Promtail deployed via Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, monitoring, promtail

I searched a lot of sites and threads and also the main documentation, but couldnt really find a good answer.

Is it possible to set up a scrape intervall for a promtail deployment ?

Theres the variable refresh_interval but im not sure if thats the correct one to set and how the syntax is supposed to look like.

Below is a sample config I want to test it with:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: syslog
      __path__: /var/log/syslog
```

Where in the config do I need to add the varaiable for the interval ?

Thanks in advance :)

The above config sends the data in certain intervals but im not sure how often.

The Grafana instance recieves the entries via loki and displays the newest every 5s, im trying to achieve a stream of logs being send to the server instead, like thats the case with greylog.